# EE2 and zoom.js bigimage=$(this)

Tags: javascript, expressionengine

I'm very novice with java :(

I have issue but with expressengine2. I have added zoom.js to product page, zoom works but not pulling ee2 large image. In zoom.js I have found 2 places with image source but cannot figure out how to insert ee2 code for image.

Zoom.js code:

```
if($("div.zoomdiv").get().length==0){$(this).after("<div class='zoomdiv'><img class='bigimg' src='"+bigimage+"'/></div>");
```

**and**

```
var bigimage=$(this).children("img").attr("jqimg");$(this).children("img").attr("alt",'');
```

**I need to insert code below:**

```
{exp:brilliant_retail:image src="{image_large}" width="390" height="320" jqimg="{image_large}"}
```

**or**

```
{image_large}
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Which jQuery Plugin are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to combine Zoom on product and additional images + FancyBox Enlarge!

I used: EE2 + Brilliantretail for EE2 + http://www.professorcloud.com/mainsite/cloud-zoom.htm + this I wrote this for ee2:

```
<div id="photos">


                <div class="large">
                        <a href="{exp:brilliant_retail:geturl type="media_url"}{image_large}" class="cloud-zoom" id="zoom1" rel="adjustX: 2, adjustY:-6, position:'inside', showTitle:true">
                        {exp:brilliant_retail:image src="{image_large}" width="390" height="470" alt='{image_title}' title='{title}'}
                        </a>

                </div>

                <div class="thumbs">
                    <ul>
                        {images}
                                                        <li><a href="{exp:brilliant_retail:geturl type="media_url"}{filenm}" title="{image_title}" rel="useZoom: 'zoom1', smallImage:'{exp:brilliant_retail:image src='{filenm}' width='390' height='470' url_only='yes'}' " class="cloud-zoom-gallery" url_only="yes"}" >{exp:brilliant_retail:image src="{filenm}" title="{title}" width="75" height="90"}</a></li>
                                {/images}
                    </ul>
                </div>


                <div class="clearboth"><!-- --></div>
            </div><!-- photos -->
```

Comment: Awesome - this is literally EXACTLY what I'm looking for. I'm doing a BR EE site. Cut and paste your code and it worked perfectly. Thanks for sharing. Jules